# How to set The values in Jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

How to set The values in Jasper report in footer section from different different table?I mean to say there are three rows in footer section and I am fetching data from views. Now my requirement is to display the data in footer section from different table in different footer rows(e.g -i.e for three rows i am using three tables)?

Comment: It will be fine if you post your question more clearly with a small image of what you expect

Answer (score 0):

How about to pass the values as parameters?

Java Side

```
// Call SQL here.
// select value1, value2, value3 from footer_table where ....

Map paramMap = new HashMap();
paramMap.put("value1", "the footer value1");
paramMap.put("value2", "the footer value2");
paramMap.put("value3", "the footer value3");

JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasper, paramMap, connection);

// Export to PDF
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print, PdfPath);
```

Jasper Side

1.Add Parameters.

```
name: value1
Parameter Class: java.lang.String
```

2.Put TextFields to footer and set the Text Field Expression.

```
$P{value1}
$P{value2}
$P{value3}
```